# Laravel 4 - How to access MySQL db in Views

Tags: php, mysql, view, laravel

I'm pretty new to using frameworks . I have a school project where i need to use an MVC and i have been using laravel for around 2 weeks .

I already setup the site structure  , authentification etc.. but i kind of hit a bump

I have no idea with laravel ,  how to use a view access a mysql table except the user one . I read several tutorials & documentation - no luck

Such as for user details - i just use these :

```
{{ Auth::user()->username }}
{{ Auth::user()->email }}
```

However i created a new model & controller . I know how to create an entry into the db table but not how to access it . Here are the files below :

Model : Course

```
<?php

class Course extends Eloquent {

    /* User Rules */

    public static $rules = array(

    'name'=>'required|alpha|size:4',

    'cid'=>'required|digits:3|unique:courses',

    'description'=>'required|regex:/^[A-Za-z \t]*$/i|min:3|unique:courses',

    'credits'=>'required|numeric'

    );

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'courses';


}
```

Controller : COurseController

```
<?php

class CourseController extends BaseController {


//------------------------------------------

public function addCourseView() {
    return View::make('courses.addcourse');
}

public function addCourse() {

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), Course::$rules);

    if ($validator->passes()) {

            $course = new Course;
            $course->name = Input::get('name');
            $course->cid = Input::get('cid');
            $course->description = Input::get('description');
            $course->credits = Input::get('credits');
            $course->save();

            return Redirect::to('courses/add')->with('status', 'Course Added Successfully !');
    } 
    else 
    {
        return Redirect::to('courses/add')->with('error', 'Errors have occured with your inputs')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }


}



}
?>
```

Now let's say i have a view .

How can i display the courses in the table using their name , cid ?

Comment: I don't know laravel but the whole idea of MVC is to keep database access out of the view.  To display data you need to fetch the data in the model, process it in the controller and pass it to the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not access or do `db` operation in your view instead you should prepare the data from your controller and pass the data fetched from the database to your view, for example, you may try something like this:

```
// Get all courses
$courses = Course::all();

// Pass data/courses to app/views/courses/index.blade.php
return View::make('courses.index')->with('courses', $courses);
```

In the view loop the courses:

```
@foreach($courses as $course)
    {{ $course->fieldName }}
@endforeach
```

This is a simplified example, you didn't provide more information so can't be more specific but just gave you the idea.